# Подключение стороннего роутера к оптоволоконной сети Ростелекома через медиаконвертер

Tags: wifi, роутер

понимаю, что вопрос немного отходит от темы сайта, за что прошу меня простить. В общем суть следующая - я решил отказаться от аренды роутера Ростелекома и подключить свой роутер, лежавший без дела (**Tp-Link AC1200**), поскольку мой роутер не имел SFP порта я купил медиаконвертер (**NetLink GE-SFP**) и SFP модуль для него (если же выбор данного медианконвертера неуместен, то скажите об этом). После недолгого шаманивания в веб морде роутера я столкнулся со странной проблемой - мой роутер не подключался к сети. Начал обзванивать Ростелеком в надежде на помощь, в ответ лишь услышал пару советов, в остальном лишь говорили что мол я не имею права менять роутер. Мой вопрос - как подключиться к сети (по поводу настроек Роутера могу сказать, что в теории они все те, которые должны быть, половину из которых я просто срисовал с роутера Ростелекома, а другую сверил с оператором), у Ростелекома нет привязки к MAC адресам, тогда что не дает моему роутеру подключиться к сети и дать мне интернет?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для начала я бы уточнил тип интерфейса на оборудовании оператора. Возможно вы пытаетесь подключиться к GPON.

Comment: Ну по сути да. А чем это чревато?

Comment: То есть в любом случае нужно докупить ONT?

Comment: Нужна поддержка GPON на абонентском терминале.

Comment: На Хабре была про это [статья](https://habr.com/ru/articles/724566/). Вас в ней заинтересует не всё, но линейная часть - то, что надо.